# aspects.jcabi: @Loggable doesn't add logs to the output

Tags: java, debugging, logging, jcabi

I am bored of adding manual logs for debugging each and every method that I write.

I came to know about `@Loggable` annotation of [jcabi](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-loggable.html) but am not successful in implementing that and your help is highly appreciated.

Below is the code that I have tried.

```
import com.jcabi.aspects.Loggable;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class Jcabi {

    @Loggable
    private static String checkJcabi(String stringToPrint) {
        log.info("Print Successfull");
        return stringToPrint;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkJcabi("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

IDE console prints this:

```
[main] INFO com.amazon.optimus.cpamutil.utils.Jcabi - Print Successfull
```

This is the log for the `log.info()` I have added in the method and there is no log for the `@Loggable` annotation something like this (below) as mentioned in this [post](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html)

```
[INFO] com.example.Foo #power(2, 10): 1024 in 12μs
[INFO] com.example.Foo #power(3, 3): 27 in 4μs
```

Below are the dependencies packages that I use:

JCabiAspects = 1.0;
AspectJ = 6.0;
Slf4j = 1.7;
Slf4j_Simple = 1.7;

Let me know if you need more details. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @santhosh Did it finally work for you? I too am stuck in a similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358784/method-with-loggable-annotation-never-prints-aspect-log

Comment: Yes we need to weave it. For eclipse try and install the aspectJ plugin. Just search aspectJ from eclipse market place

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and I installed AspectJ plugin for IntelliJ but that did not help :(

Comment: In eclipse, i used to install the plugin and in run as i need to run as Aspect J application and not as java one.

Comment: This plugin is a joke, does not work.

Comment: It really worked. We need to weave the source code it. In eclipse you can try install aspecj from the market place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do weaving of your binaries, as explained here: http://aspects.jcabi.com/example-weaving.html

Comment: How can that be done when you run your code not from maven but from an IDE like eclipse/Intellij through a test runner class like a JUnit class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the binary weaving. In the post that you linked, it says so and it also says that you can use the jcabi-maven-plugin to do the weaving for you, given that you are using maven.

> Just add a few dependencies to your classpath and configure jcabi-maven-plugin for aspect weaving (get their latest versions in Maven Central)

```
<project>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>ajc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

If you are using gradle, you can use this [gradle-aspectj-binary](https://github.com/sedovalx/gradle-aspectj-binary) plugin