# Method with @Loggable annotation never prints aspect log

Tags: java, spring, logging, aspectj, jcabi

I want to implement the ability to log entry and exit of some methods that are annotated with some annotation (For example: `@Loggable`). I came across AspectJ AOP using which we can do this.

I implemented a custom aspect of my own to customise the log message I want to print on entry and exit of the method that gets called with `@Loggable`:

```
@Aspect
public final class MethodLogger {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodLogger.class);

  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Loggable)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {

    String className = MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getClass().getName();
    String methodName = MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod().getName();
    LOG.info(
        "Entering method:{}() of class:{} with parameters: {}",
        methodName,
        className,
        Arrays.toString(point.getArgs()));

    try
    {
      return point.proceed();
    }
    catch(Throwable e){
       throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
      LOG.info(
          "Exiting method:{}() of class:{} with parameters: {}",
          methodName,
          className,
          Arrays.toString(point.getArgs()));
    }

  }
}
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>0.22.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Class that has a method annotated with `@Loggable`:

```
@Component
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

@Loggable
public Object login(String username, String password) {

}

}
```

**Problem**:

When this instance method (`login()`)is called mostly in the following manner:
`loginPage.login()`, I cannot see the entry and exit log being printed to the log output.

Please note:

- I am using Spring dependency injection to initialise such classes with `@Component` annotation, not sure if that is useful information for the forum but still letting you all know.
- This is a test automation project where I am triggering some UI automated tests from a JUnit+Cucumber runner class.
- I am not triggering my tests from maven.

Can someone suggest what could be going wrong here?

Comment: have you tried with the full path of your annotation?

Comment: I haven't created a separate annotation. I am using AspectJ's @Loggable annotation.

Comment: what kind of weaving are you using ? if you are using compile time weaving, check if the aspects are successfully weaved in to your .class file

Comment: I am not sure how aspectj weaving should occur when you are not running the code from maven but directly running a class (test runner class in my case) from an IDE. I am using IntelliJ

Comment: Post your test code and configuration. How are you configuring this aspect?

Comment: AspectJ does not have any `@Loggable` annotation. What are you talking about? BTW, posting your project or at least an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) distilled from it on GitHub would be a good idea.

Comment: One more thing: Why are you not using Maven to run your tests? When that works you can still try to run them from an IDE or command line separately. Try to limit the number of possible error sources.

Comment: @kriegaex I am using the Loggable annotation of jcabi-aspects

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. In your previous comment you said AspectJ. So how about the MCVE? M.Deinum is right, we need more information, not just bits and pieces.

Comment: Hello again. I still have this question on my follow-up list. So did you prepare the MCVE? Or have you at least added `@Component` to your aspect and changed your pointcut to use a fully the qualified class name  `@annotation(com.jcabi.aspects.Loggable)`? Both is necessary, maybe it already fixes the problem. Otherwise you have a configuration problem. Please respond.

Answer (score 1):

You aspect `MethodLogger` is not initialized yet.Try adding `@Component` to the `MethodLogger`. This should load and register the aspect into the context, making it ready for use.

Also you might want to simplify your point cut `@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Loggable)")`.

`execution(* *(..))` is basically a wild card and therefore useless. Just use`@Around("@annotation(Loggable)")`.